# Graph terminology : name for vertex with edge

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a name for a node and an in- or outgoing edge from that node as a unity in graph terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The original question:*

> Is there a name for a exactly one vertex with exactly one edge in graph terminology?

It's a node of degree/valence $1$, sometimes called a *leaf* or an *end*.

This all appears in the [wiki on degree (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)).

> Is there a name for a node and an in- or outgoing edge from that node as a unity[...]?

I guess you mean "as a unit" as in "one term for the two things together." I don't see why anyone would need something more complicated than "an edge $E$ incident on $V$" or "endpoint $V$ of edge $E$."

To me, endpoints are already fully integrated into their edge. What is an edge without its endpoints? Can you even talk about them "not as a unit?"

Comment: Ah, just realized that what I am looking for is NOT necessarily a node with exactly one edge. I'm actually looking for term that describes a node with any single out- or ingoing edge as a unity. So not a leaf in other words. Sorry - changing the question.

Comment: I redacted a comment as I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @swelet FFR understand that in general it is bad form to completely reword a question. To avoid this situation, carefully think about what you've written in your question before submitting.

Comment: @rschwieb I know, but thanks for pointing it out. Maybe I should have let your first answer do and asked a new question. Thanks for the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

"a node with any out or incoming relationship as a unity" - How about a non-isolated node?